# Storing user input from multiple fields in different columns of Laravel database table

Tags: php, laravel, database, frontend, backend

I have a iage selling and buying multi vendor site like shutterstock and it was developed with laravel php. And there is a page called payouts and it refers to the withdrawals-configure.blade.php. However when the user input their bank details into the input field and save it will be stored at the database ‘users’ table ‘bank’ column.

Now I have added more input fields to the page and they are ‘Bank Code’ , ‘Branch Code’ , ‘Account Number’ and ‘ Account Name’ I have written the code for these inputs in withdrawal-configure.blade.php file but the function that i have written in DashboardController.php is not storing data in database.

I have a image selling and buying multi vendor site like shutterstock and it was developed with laravel php. And there is a page called payouts and it refers to the withdrawals-configure.blade.php. However when the user input their bank details into the input field and save it will be stored at the database ‘users’ table ‘bank’ column.

Here’s the code for that process:

```
<!-- ***** FORM ***** -->
        <form action="{{ url('user/withdrawals/configure/bank') }}" method="post" name="form" class="mb-5">

            <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">

            <div class="form-floating mb-3"> <!-- Bank Name -->
             <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="{{ trans('misc.bank_details') }}" name="bank" id="input-bank_details" style="height: 100px">{{ auth()->user()->bank }}</textarea>
             <label for="input-bank_details">{{ trans('misc.bank_details') }}</label>
           </div>
           
            <button type="submit" class="btn w-100 btn-lg btn-custom">{{ trans('misc.save_payout_method') }}</button>
        </form><!-- ***** END FORM ***** -->
```

Now I have added more input fields to the page and they are ‘Bank Code’ , ‘Branch Code’ , ‘Account Numbe’ and ‘ Account Name’ I have written the code for these inputs in the **withdrawal-configure.blade.php** file:

```
<div class="form-floating mb-3"> <!-- Bank Code -->
             <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="{{ trans('misc.bank_details') }}" name="bank_code" id="input-bank_code" style="height: 100px" maxlength="4" size="4">{{ auth()->user()->bank_code }}</textarea>
             <label for="input-bank_code">Bank Code</label> 
           </div>
           
            <div class="form-floating mb-3"> <!-- Branch Code -->
             <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="{{ trans('misc.bank_details') }}" name="branch_code" id="input-branch_code" style="height: 100px" maxlength="4" size="4">{{ auth()->user()->branch_code }}</textarea>
             <label for="input-branch_code">Branch Code</label>
           </div>

            <div class="form-floating mb-3"> <!-- Account Number -->
             <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="{{ trans('misc.bank_details') }}" name="ac_num" id="input-ac_num" style="height: 100px">{{ auth()->user()->ac_num }}</textarea>
             <label for="input-ac_num">Account Number</label>
           </div>
           
            <div class="form-floating mb-3"> <!-- Account Name -->
             <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="{{ trans('misc.bank_details') }}" name="ac_name" id="input-ac_name" style="height: 100px">{{ auth()->user()->ac_name }}</textarea>
             <label for="input-ac_name">Account Name</label>
           </div>
```

And Now I want to program to store the data in different columns in the ‘users’ table when user types and saves in the other input fields. However I have attached the regarding function this on **DashboardController.php**

```
    public function withdrawalConfigure()
    {
      if ($this->request->type != 'paypal' && $this->request->type != 'bank') {
        return redirect('user/dashboard/withdrawals/configure')->withError(__('misc.error'));
      }

    // Validate Email Paypal
    if ($this->request->type == 'paypal') {
      $rules = [
          'email_paypal'  => 'required|email|confirmed',
        ];

    $this->validate($this->request, $rules);

    $user = User::find(auth()->id());
    $user->paypal_account = $this->request->email_paypal;
    $user->payment_gateway = 'PayPal';
    $user->save();

    return redirect('user/dashboard/withdrawals/configure')->withSuccess(__('admin.success_update'));

    } else if ($this->request->type == 'bank') {

      $rules = [
          'bank' => 'required',
        ];

      $this->validate($this->request, $rules);

       $user = User::find(auth()->id());
       $user->bank = $this->request->bank;
       $user->payment_gateway = 'Bank';
       $user->save();

      return redirect('user/dashboard/withdrawals/configure')->withSuccess(__('admin.success_update'));
    }

    }//<--- End Method
```

Can you help me to write the code to store and update these data on DB on **DashboardController.php** file please

Comment: What's the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The new form fields need to be in the field.
2. You may need to add the new fields to the fillable array in the User model.
3. You need to add the new fields you want to the rules.
4. You add the new form fields to the `$user->column_name = $this->request->field_name` before you save the model. ex: `$user->bank_code = $this->request->bank_code`

You also do not need that else in there since you have an early return in the if and the second case can just be an if. And lastly, you can return null after both if statements.